# T-R3X the look My Block problems

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

OK I am making the look My block for the T-R3X program but there is this block which don't know how to make at the end of the diagram in the book.

Comment: Hi Aseehah! This question is hardly answerable without an illustration of the diagram in question. Could you upload a photo or a picture to show the part you are having problems with?